# print formatting with strings

Tags: string, python-3.x

```
a = [('sample\\assignments.html', 'C:\\Users\\AJ\\Desktop\\sample\\sample\\projects.html', 'sample\\projects.html', False),('sample\\assignments.html','C:\\Users\\AJ\\Desktop\\sample\\sample\\docs-assets\\ico\\favicon.png', 'sample\\docs-assets\\ico\\favicon.png', False)]
print("Broken link")
print("{:>0}{:>35}".format("Source HTML","Link"))
print("============================================================")
for item in a:
   b = list(item)
   print("{:>0}{:>35}".format(b[0],b[2]))
```

print result:

```
Broken link
Source HTML                          Link
============================================================
sample\assignments.html               sample\projects.html
sample\assignments.html sample\docs-assets\ico\favicon.png
sample\index.html      sample\dist\css\bootstrap.css
sample\testkeys.html            sample\assignments.html
sample\testkeys.html                  sample\index.html
```

Can someone correct my codes so that all the texts in the second column "Link" are aligned, or lined up?

In my program, the "a" list contains many tuples where b[0] and b[2] are different in length.

i'm really not sure how the .format() and the spaces indicator inside the {} work.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you want is to allign the columns. Which means you should padd all string with whitespaces sush that they have equal length and then add `\t` if needed or more whitespaces. I am not sure if there is something that already does that in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("{:<26}{}".format("Source HTML","Link"))
print("="*60)
for item in a:
   b = list(item)
   print("{:<26}{}".format(b[0],b[2]))
```

Output:

```
Broken link
Source HTML               Link
============================================================
sample\assignments.html   sample\projects.html
sample\assignments.html   sample\docs-assets\ico\favicon.png
```